# App_Offline.htm being created by Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to run a web application project that was mostly developed with Visual Studio 2015. However, I never created the file "App_Offline.htm" file. No one on my team added it, either. It just randomly showed up while running Visual Studio 2017 and testing it out.

Looking up the issue on here, I found [This application is currently offline. To enable the application, remove the app_offline.htm file from the application root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497257/this-application-is-currently-offline-to-enable-the-application-remove-the-app) where an answer stated:

> > Just go to the root of your web directory, it should be there. it is something that VS puts there during certain tasks.

This is unacceptable behaviour for testing a web application. This version of Visual Studio is unusable if Visual Studio "just decides" to make my web application offline. This answer/question is for an earlier version of Visual Studio, but if this feature used to be there then I assume that it must still be there because it seems to be the only way the file showed up.

What specific tasks would make this file appear in the solution folder? How can I prevent it?

Comment: There is nothing that would cause that, save for explicitly adding the file yourself. If that wasn't you, perhaps another developer on your team did it? Regardless, there's no way to "prevent it" as it's not something that happens without human intervention.

Comment: Funny, the quote you posted from the other answer was from 2010. So, clearly it does not apply specifically to either Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.

Comment: @NightOwl888 and Chris Pratt No, I did not add it and no one on my team added it. The feature either used to be there in Visual Studio or the answer provided was wrong in the question I linked. If it used to be there and no one on my team added it, then it stands to reason that the claim made in the question I linked remains true. If you would like, I can remove the tag for Visual Studio 2017 and edit the question to ask "What specific tasks did that answer refer to" if that's what it takes to get a solid answer that I can use to fix the problem. A human did **not** do it, so I need an answer.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Also, "It was for an earlier version so it does not apply to this version" does not follow. If the feature was never removed then it very well can still apply to Visual Studio 2017, hence why I believed it was relevant.

Comment: @TheAnathema - But your question seems to imply the problem doesn't exist in VS 2015, but does in VS 2017.

Comment: @NightOwl888 No, the implication that it never happened in 2015. That doesn't mean it couldn't happen, only that it didn't. The linked question I provided is there as a starting point for anyone to think of an automatic process that would yield that file's presence. The answer given by Travis Acton suggests that there is such an automatic process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs when someone from your team kicks off a web deploy. It first reaches out to the mapped IIS directory and removes all the files and places that file in there (and maps to it for anyone hitting the page) until your new build is fully deployed. VS doesn't just decide to do things, it was being reactive to one of your team members actions. The web deploy probably failed and you got stuck with this file there instead of an empty directory. It should have given whoever kicked off the deploy a fat failed error.

I believe there is a full web deploy log located on the server event viewer under Apps and services logs > Microsoft > Windows > WebDeploy thatyou can check

There should also be something under Inetpub > logs as well.

This is something that most people do not know unless they are specifically watching the folder structure during a deploy. You would also start to become more highly aware of it if you were using TFS auto builds and customizing build templates.

Sorry for your frustration.

Comment: Thank you for providing a possible reason. There are no events listed in the Event Viewer and no such web deployment was executed. The actions taken were: 1 - Open local copy of solution via Visual Studio 2017. 2 - Run the web application. 3 - Discover that it cannot find the site url because I'm not running in administrator mode (perhaps relevant, but this was yesterday.) 4 - Set VS to administrator mode. 5 - Run web application again this morning, file gets generated I believe around the same time. I did not get latest from TFS and no one would have checked that file in.

Comment: Definitely weird, are you using TFS builds at all?

Comment: Also note that the file in question is not part of your solution that gets checked in, it's part of the deploy process. A good place to start (probably too late now) but if you see it then the file datetime is when the deploy event occurred. Usually one would go and explicitly go to the publish options on the solution and click deploy but you can also have it baked into TFS builds so that if someone kicks off a specific build in TFS, deploy is an action it takes. That has to be defined explicitly though when setting up the build templates. Regardless, this is an indication of a deploy action.